# How can I start SpiderOak automatically on a headless server?

Tags: services, upstart

I use [SpiderOak](http://www.spideroak.com) for online backup and file synchronisation (a la Dropbox.) I'm running it on my headless server via the `SpiderOak --headless` command.

At the moment, I have to start this manually inside a screen session to keep it running. This means I have to remember to start my backup software each time I restart the server (not ideal.)

How can I start SpiderOak automatically with the rest of the system processes? (For extra points, how can I monitor it to make sure it stays alive?)

I've tried adding a `spideroak.conf` file to the Upstart services in `/etc/init` as shown below, but it fails to start because SpiderOak needs to run as my normal user account (not root.)

```
root@helios:~/.SpiderOak# cat /etc/init/spideroak.conf
description "The SpiderOak automatic cloud backup service."

# Start when system starts.
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

exec SpiderOak --headless
```

Answer (score 10):

This is what I use in order to get SpiderOak to automatically start after a reboot on my headless server (Ubuntu 12.04).  I use `cron` with the following entry:

```
@reboot /sbin/start-stop-daemon -b -x /usr/bin/SpiderOak -S -- --headless
```

checking the `syslog` I can confirm it starts up and using top I can confirm its running after reboot.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What does the "-S" option do?  It tells me there's "no such option".  Also, why the "--" before the "--headless"?

Comment: Don't worry about it.  I just realized that those are start-stop-daemon options, not SpiderOak options.